# Basic .gitlab-ci.yml file with build and test jobs for .net project

Tags: .net, msbuild, gitlab-ci, xunit, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to create a CI pipeline in gitlab to build and run unit tests on my .net project using msbuild for building, and xunit for testing. My gitlab runner and such is set up fine, I am just having trouble with writing the yaml file in gitlab itself. There also does not seem to be many resources on this area, especially xunit testing.

Below is an example of what I have right now, as well as what the build job and test job shell output looks like.

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Tools\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  XUNIT_PATH: packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\tools\net452
  UNITTEST_FOLDER: '.\tests\development-testing.Tests\bin\Release\'

stages:
  - build
  - test

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "restoring nuget packages..."
    - cd src\prototype
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore' # restore Nuget dependencies
    - echo "buliding..."
    - '"$MSBUILD_PATH" src\prototype\proto.sln' # build the project
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 days
    paths:
      - "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"
      - '.\"$XUNIT_PATH"\*.*'

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "testing..."
    - '"$XUNIT_PATH"\xunit.console.exe "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"\test1.dll'
    - '"$XUNIT_PATH"\xunit.console.exe "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"\test2.dll'
  dependencies:
    - build_job
```

**build job output:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (____)
  on proto testing pipeline ____, system ID: _____
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on ____...
Getting source from Git repository
00:07
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/zFhd5DhG/0/____/development/.git/
Checking out ____ as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
At line:275 char:17
+ "$MSBUILD_PATH" src\prototype\proto.sln
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'src\prototype\proto.sln' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:3
+ & {
+   ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
At line:1 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Version:      16.2.0
Git revision: ____
Git branch:   16-2-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-07-21T22:53:19+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=____
revision=____ version=16.2.0
WARNING: invalid path "": 1:15: reached EOF without closing quote ` 
WARNING: .\tests\development-testing.Tests\bin\Release\: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\zFhd5DhG\0\____\development-testing) 
WARNING: .\`$XUNIT_PATH`\*.*: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\zFhd5DhG\0\____\development-testing) 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

**test job output:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (____)
  on proto testing pipeline ____, system ID: ____
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on ____...
Getting source from Git repository
00:05
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/zFhd5DhG/0/____/development-testing/.git/
Checking out ____ as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git ____)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
At line:266 char:14
+ "$XUNIT_PATH"\xunit.console.exe "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"\test1 ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\xunit.console.exe' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:3
+ & {
+   ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
$ "$XUNIT_PATH"\xunit.console.exe "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"\test2.dll
At line:1 char:14
+ "$XUNIT_PATH"\xunit.console.exe "$UNITTEST_FOLDER"\test2 ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\xunit.console.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
At line:1 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

I basically went off of this template here:
https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f

I do not understand what `XUNIT_PATH` should point to though. Is that something on gitlab or on my C drive?

I also do not undersatnd what `UNITTEST_FOLDER` is? Is that the path it creates to write the built binaries to?

My general idea is that I want to be able to build the solution in the build job and store those binaries in a location. Then I want to access those binaries in the test job to use xunit to run the test.dll files that were built from the solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some help to get started.
`Nuget restore` without more parametes, causes problems in many cases, I'm looking in a more robust way to tackle that.
It's also recommended to restore your solution before building it and add some properties to your project for example:
`& $MSBUILD_PATH "SolutionFile.sln" /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`
and after that run the build command:
`& $MSBUILD_PATH /restore "SolutionFile.snl /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`